# CronTrigger misfire instruction is not set with CronTriggerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I'm creating a Quartz job with the following Spring XML configuration:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
            <property name="name" value="The job"/>
            <property name="group" value="The group"/>
            <property name="jobClass" value="com.example.myapp.MorningJob"/>
            <property name="jobDataMap">
                <util:map>
                    <entry key="key1"
                           value="val1"/>
                    <entry key="key2"
                           value="val2"/>
                </util:map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 * * ? *"/>
    <property name="misfireInstruction"
        value="#{T(org.quartz.CronTrigger).MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW}"/>
    <property name="timeZone" ref="timezone"/>
</bean>
```

My job looks like this

```java
@Configurable
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class MorningJob implements Job { ... }
```

However, misfire instruction set has no effect at all. After long app downtime, when the trigger missed multiple times, Quartz tries to start the job many times.

When I'd tried to check `context.getTrigger().getMisfireInstruction()` from `MorningJob.execute()` it gives 0, while `CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW` is 1.

Any ideas why misfire instruction is not set?

Comment: quartz version I'm using is 2.1.5 and Spring version 4.0.5.RELEASE.

Comment: Can you post the complete `CronTriggerFactoryBean` config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually in my scheduler configuration. In the declaration of `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean` I had a property

```xml
<property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="false"/>
```

Initially, for testing purposes I've configured my trigger to run each few seconds just to see it fires properly. `overwriteExistingJobs` meant the trigger saved in database wasn't actually updated after change of cron expression and `misfireInstruction` wasn't actually applied as well. To update the trigger I need either to run `scheduler.clear()` once or set the mentioned property to true for a while.

I'm sure this should be mentioned more clearly in the documentation as it could be really frustrating to not have a trigger configuration updated after each change. `false` is the default value of `overwriteExistingJobs`.